How to use helm for editing existing file links in org mode?
In Org mode, when I insert a new link to a local file using C-u C-c C-l, the Helm interface opens, allowing me to conveniently choose the file from my system. However, when I move the point to an existing link to a local file and press the same key sequence (C-u C-c C-l), I can only edit the file path directly in the minibuffer, and the Helm interface doesn't open.
Is there a built-in way to invoke Helm when editing an existing file link in Org mode, similar to when inserting a new link? If not, what's the best way to achieve this behavior?

When point is on an existing file link, org uses read-string directly. There's no easy way I can see to change that short of changing the org source directly (or asking the org developers to change it).
